# Span two harddrives without formating the first one

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

I'm thinking of merging two hard drives and the word spanning pops up a lot, but the thing is to span the two hard drives we have to format both the discs but that's not an option for me as i need the data on the first hard disk. is there any way to join the second one without having to format the old one?

Comment: Do you need data that's currently on the _second_ disk? (Also, does either of the disks include the Windows OS itself?)

Comment: What, specifically, are you attempting to accomplish by "spanning" or "merging" these drives?

Comment: AFAIK you can convert partition to dynamic, then it should be possible to span across multiple drives, but I'm not sure about booting from dynamic partition.

Comment: Windows doesn’t support it.

Comment: im using a drive to store a lot of docs. now the drive is almost full. so i need a new one to merge into this one. hence can't afford formatting the old one. and none of the discs have any os in them @grawity

Comment: Then format the _new_ one first, and move data over?

Comment: Consider rearranging your filing system on the original drive and mount the new drive as a directory on the old one (Windows can do this), then move some of the (rearranged) files onto the new drive by moving them into the directory where you mounted the new drive.

Comment: Or, just deal with having two separate drives for your documents...